# font() pen only works once, then falls back to default font

Tags: fonts, mac, asymptote

I'm trying to draw a bunch of labels with a custom font, installed in `~/Library/Fonts`. To do this, I create a `pen` using `font()` and then use that pen with `label()`:

```
pen font_pen = font("DejaVuSans", 24);

label("First", (0mm, 0mm), font_pen);
label("Second", (0mm, -10mm), font_pen);
```

Then I compile the file as follows:

```
$ asy -f pdf -tex xelatex test_fonts.asy

kpathsea: Running mktextfm DejaVuSans
/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation D for DejaVuSans.
/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input DejaVuSans
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2015/MacPorts 2015_7) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf DejaVuSans
! I can't find file `DejaVuSans'.
<*> ...four; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input DejaVuSans

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...four; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input DejaVuSans

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: DejaVuSans.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input DejaVuSans' failed to make DejaVuSans.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm DejaVuSans
/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation D for DejaVuSans.
/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input DejaVuSans
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2015/MacPorts 2015_7) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf DejaVuSans
! I can't find file `DejaVuSans'.
<*> ...four; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input DejaVuSans

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...four; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input DejaVuSans

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: DejaVuSans.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input DejaVuSans' failed to make DejaVuSans.tfm.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm DejaVuSans
/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation D for DejaVuSans.
/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input DejaVuSans
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2015/MacPorts 2015_7) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf DejaVuSans
! I can't find file `DejaVuSans'.
<*> ...four; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input DejaVuSans

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...four; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input DejaVuSans

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: DejaVuSans.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input DejaVuSans' failed to make DejaVuSans.tfm.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm DejaVuSans
/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation D for DejaVuSans.
/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input DejaVuSans
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2015/MacPorts 2015_7) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf DejaVuSans
! I can't find file `DejaVuSans'.
<*> ...four; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input DejaVuSans

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...four; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input DejaVuSans

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: DejaVuSans.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input DejaVuSans' failed to make DejaVuSans.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of Result]

Why is only the first label using the specified font and how can I draw multiple labels with a single pen specifying a custom font?

I'm using Asymptote 2.36 on OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: It doesn't know anything about the font you are trying to use. That's why you get all those errors complaining about the missing font. And why it writes you a special log file, `missfont.log`, to tell you about it.

Comment: I think it looks for a font with the wrong name. On my system, the font's name is DejaVu Sans (with a space). However, it doesn't like the space either. I can get it to look for the right font with `{}`. But... are you sure this is supposed to work? It seems to be using TeX font commands, which is not likely to work with arbitrary system fonts.

Comment: @cfr Well, it does work for one of the labels, so _somehow_ XeLaTeX is finding the right font file. I also tried it with some other fonts I installed manually (e.g. `OfficinaSansITC-Book`) with the same result: The first label uses the correct font, the others don't.

Comment: @cfr If there's another way to include a custom font, event by passing the full path to it, I'd be happy to do that. But I couldn't find another way as of yet.

Comment: Apparently. But I don't understand why it works at all. Judging from the answer you've got, I guess I'm not alone in this :(.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick look at the documentation of asymptote makes me think using `font` in this way can not work, but I don't know why it seems to work for the first label. Anyway, does this help ?

```
texpreamble("\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{American Typewriter}");
label("First", (0mm, 0mm),currentpen+fontsize(36pt)+blue);
label("Second", (0mm, -10mm),currentpen+fontsize(36pt)+red);
```

and then

```
$ asy -f pdf -tex xelatex test_fonts.asy
```

produces:

> [image: Blockquote]

I used Mac OS X 10.9.5 `American Typewriter` system font. Here is with another system font, `Herculanum`:

> [image: enter code here]

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem. I found out that I can change the font of a single label using e.g. `label({\setmainfont{Herculanum} Second}", ...)`. Still wondering why my original attempt worked for a single label …

Comment: good to know about `\setmainfont` usable in `label`... I have absolutely no idea why your original attempt worked for one label !